# Creating a backup array with DOM objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, select

I've got `<select>` element **a** with different `option`s. When loading the page, I want to store these `option`s as a backup (I'm doing this with `window.onload`).

Now the user changes `<select>` element **b**, which removes some `option`s in `<select>` element **a**. After some other change on `<select>` element **b**, I want to restore the `option`s of element **a** with my backup from the startup.

But no matter what, the changes on the `option`s seem to apply to both arrays.

I've created the backup arrray with `new Array` and `push`ed each of the `option`s into the new array. I hoped that this would prevent them from being removed from the array when they're removed from the DOM.

Any hints how I can solve this problem?

---

```
function cacheOptions() {
    backupOptions = newArray(document.getElementById("selectElement").options);
}

function newArray(oldArray) {
    var newArray = new Array(oldArray.length);
    for ( var object in oldArray) {
        newArray.push(object);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

And removing the `option`s in an `onchange` method …

```
document.getElementById("selectElement").options[i].remove();
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: what does your html look like

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use `for in` to loop over an array; use a normal `for` loop
2. You can make an array with `arr = []`; the length will be set automatically
3. You're appending the indexes of the old array to the new array; not their values

Anyhow, you can just use `[].slice.call(arr)` to get an array from an array-like object.

So, you'd best get rid of the `newArray` function, and change the `cacheOptions` function to:

```
function cacheOptions() {
    backupOptions = [].slice.call(document.getElementById("selectElement").options);
}
```

Comment: When I use your code, I can remove one element from the DOM model and it still stays in the other one. BUT when I reset the options with `= backupArray` nothing gets inserted. Even stranger: The options deleted fomr the DOM model are display transparent in Firebug.

Comment: I've got to correct myself: Both arrays still use hold the same objects.